# Cannot remove "invalid" item from keychain

Tags: macos, mac, keychain

An application I use (Omnifocus) needs to login to a sync server so it needs to store credentials in the keychain. After a long time of not using it, when I open it now it keeps asking me for login/password every time, like it cannot get them from the keychain.
[image]

If I try to delete the keychain file I get an error:
[image]

I have tried to repair the keychain with keychain first aid, but I'm still getting the same error message on delete.

Is there some more "forceful" way to delete (or repair) them? Maybe on command line or something

Comment: Restart the keychain. That should help.

Comment: You mean "restart" or "reset"?

Comment: I mean restart. Often, that helps. I had the same issue.

Comment: How can you do that?

Comment: Just close the tool and open it again.

Comment: Nah, still doesn't work :(